# Python2: Fitting a multi-parameter sum of functions with scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, curve-fitting, least-squares

This is my first post on Stack Overflow so please be patient if any info is missing.

I am trying to fit a function through data using Python 2.7.15 (ubuntu 18.04) with scipy.optimize.curve_fit(). This fitting function consists of a sum of a variable number of exponentials with associated parameters which are passed through the *args parameter of my fitting function.

I have tried passing vectors of parameters to my fitting function. Unfortunately, it seems like the sum of exponentials I perform with a 'for' loop is actually interpreted as a numpy. ndarray, where it should be a single value to be returned to the fitting algorithm.
Find below a (simplified) example of what I tried:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import math
from scipy import optimize

# Fitting function:
def fitFuncTau(amplitude, nFit, t, *args):
    C0=args[0]
    C=list(args[1:(nFit+1)])
    tau=list(args[(nFit+1):(2*nFit+2)])
    sumFit=0
    for i in range(0, nFit):
        sumFit+=C[i]*np.exp(-t/tau[i])
    print sumFit
    return C0+amplitude*sumFit

#Fitting Args: C0 parameter, then two lists C[] and tau[] (size Nfit)
fitArgs=[1, 0.01, 0.01, 0.1, 0.1]
nFit=2
amplitude=1

# Dummy fitting data
x=np.linspace(0, 4, 100)
np.random.seed(1729)
y=np.random.normal(size=x.size)

#Fit
wrapFunc=lambda t, *args: fitFuncTau(amplitude, nFit, t, *args)
fit_opt, fit_cov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(wrapFunc, x, y, p0=fitArgs)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not really relevant to provide you an answer, but `sum` is a python built-in function. Do not use `sum` as a variable name.

Comment: Good point, thanks for that! Just updated it.

Comment: But `fit_opt` is correct? Does the result make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use your `fitFuncTau` function standalone. `fitFuncTau(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)` (or whatever values you want to provide to fill the correct amount of parameters) prints just a number, not a list.

I cannot find any doc or reference to prove it, but I guess is just a printing optimization done by `curve_fit()`.
All the `print` calls due to each element of `x` are collected in a list and the list is printed. If you check the length of the printed list is the same of your `x` array (100 in your case).

It should not affect the result of the fit. Check if the values in `fit_opt` are reasonable.